# How to execute a multiple line mysql query in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I've a multiple line SQL Query which creates a pivot table. Now I want to run this query using PHP. I tried running it using PDO but it returns an error.

This is PHP code that I wrote

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $dbname = "logs";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        die($ex->getMessage());
    }

    $query = "start transaction;
    SET @sql = NULL;
    SET @@group_concat_max_len = 5000;
    SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
            'MAX(IF(cropname = ''',
            cropname,
            ''', quantity, NULL)) AS ''',
            cropname,''''
        )
    ) INTO @sql
    FROM
        tempcrop;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT date, SUM(quantity),', @sql, ' FROM tempcrop Group By date');

        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        commit;";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $cropData = array();

    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $cropData['AllCrops'][] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($cropData);
?>
```

How can I run this query using PHP.

Comment: What error(s) did you get? This is not called a multiple lines query, but they are simply multiple queries. You could run each query separately.

Comment: Or get your SQL inside to a stored procedure and call this procedure after

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error'